Why do Homeomorphisms imply completeness between a complete Vector space and an arbitrary one?
Why does a homeomorphism between a norms vector space imply that completeness transfers?
In class today, my professor stated that because we know that any two finite dimensional normed vector spaces are homeomorphic (say $\mathbb R^n$ and $V$), that we know the $V$ is complete as $\mathbb{R^n}$ is complete.
Why does completeness “transfer” for lack of a better word?

It is true that a normed space is a Banach space if and only if it is homeomorphic to a Banach space, see for instance this MO post. I don't know if this is the intended argument.

I’m only asking for the if direction, i.e. if a normes vector space is finite dimensional then it is a banach space, with an argument dealing with the homeomorphism to $\mathbb R^n$. I read that post and I don’t understand the first answer mainly because of notation but also because my topology knowledge is minimal, and I have not had time to read the paper the second answer looked for.

The "only if" direction is obvious, I just threw it in myself: a Banach space is homeomorphic to itself. In fact, the post does not prove it. Personally, I've just looked at the answer that does not cite an article. I must clarify that I don't wish to reverse-engineer your professor's idea and I won't provide further elaboration.
